# How to fetch the elements from the given nested array?

Tags: php, android, json

i get a jsonobject from android and get it in this format after decoding it using json_decode(), now i want to insert these data into the database. How do i fetch these data, please help...
thankyou in advance...

```
Array
 (
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => ramesh
            [empid] => emp32451
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => Ranjith
            [empid] => emp89884
        )
)
```

php:

```
<?php

header('Content-type: application/json');
$decoded= json_decode($_POST['submit_data']);
json_encode($decoded);
$emplist = $decoded;
print_r ($emplist);
?>
```

Comment: you are just printing your arrary from your php server try converting this array into json (json_encode(array)) and then parse that json this data is not parseable in android

Comment: Sir i had tried encoding using the following code(edited)...  but i am not able to put the array to insert the data

Comment: Sorry sir ... ive attached the code now ... thank you

Comment: remove this line print_r ($emplist);

Comment: Sir later can i fetch the array elements, using for loop ? please help ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this where the print_r() line is to get the values from the array.

```
for ( $i = 0; $i < count( $emplist ); $i++ ) {
  $name = $emplist[$i]["name"];
  $empid = $emplist[$i]["empid"];

  // write to the database in the database's specified manner
}
```